# How to calculate weighted average with 3 parameters

Tags: math, formula, average, mathematical-optimization, weighted-average

I have below data. I need to figure out "Does italy has as much spam problem as spain does" ?

| country | month | spam_complaints | total_users | tot_calls_received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spain | Jan21. | 10 | 10 | 100 |
| spain | Feb21. | 20 | 15 | 200 |
| Italy | Jan21 | 5 | 4 | 50 |
| Italy | Feb21 | 2 | 2 | 30 |
| spain | mar21. | 30 | 20 | 150 |
| spain | apr21. | 20 | 15 | 100 |
| Italy | mar21 | 10 | 8 | 50 |
| Italy | apr21 | 8 | 8 | 80 |

Is it logical to consider (spam_complaints * total_users) / total_calls_received as a formula ?
I am trying to put as much sense into it as i can. Any help is appreciated to logically resolve the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since a user can make N complaints, I don't see an accurate formula to be applied here. I suggest you post this question in Mathematics forum since it is not computer related.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest any forum link ?

Comment: Yes: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you could just compute sum(spam_complaints) / sum(tot_calls_received) and ignore the total_users?